# Android youtube extractor library returns null on response

Tags: java, android

I am using [Commit451 youtube extractor](https://github.com/Commit451/YouTubeExtractor) library to extract youtube videos in Android Studio but the problem I am facing is that I get a null response.
this is my code:

```
   String id = "WN4Xec0bNmo";
    YouTubeExtractor extractor = YouTubeExtractor.create();
    extractor.extract(id).enqueue(new Callback<YouTubeExtractionResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<YouTubeExtractionResult> call, Response<YouTubeExtractionResult> response) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response.body(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<YouTubeExtractionResult> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error "+t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the complete URL in id.

Incorrect : String id = "WN4Xec0bNmo";

Correct: String id = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN4Xec0bNmo